# How to add %u after every fourth digit in a long string

Tags: excel, function

I have so many long long strings like:
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

I would like to add `%u` after every four digits to make it a proper Unicode. the strings are of different sizes.

Can anyone help me with an Excel function?

Comment: Just add '%U' as string after every 4 digits?

Answer (score 1):

Try this small **UDF()**:

```
Public Function StringFixer(inpt As String) As String
  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  i = Len(inpt) - 3
  For j = 1 To i Step 4
    StringFixer = StringFixer & "%u" & Mid(inpt, j, 4)
  Next j
  StringFixer = Mid(StringFixer, 3) & "%u"
End Function
```

with data in **A1**, in **A2** enter:

```
=StringFixer(A1)
```

Your example:

[image]

**EDIT#1**

To place the separator at the **beginning** of each four character set rather than **after** each four character set, use this version:

```
Public Function StringFixer(inpt As String) As String
  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  i = Len(inpt) - 3
  For j = 1 To i Step 4
    StringFixer = StringFixer & "%u" & Mid(inpt, j, 4)
  Next j
End Function
```

Comment: @HusnainNaz  See my **EDIT#1**